# Invariant sets of functions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-geometry

Let $I$ be a set of differentiable functions on a manifold $M$. Consider $X$ a vector field on $M$ such that leaves $I$ invariant, i.e.,
$$ X \left( M \right)$$
Then, the set of common zeros $Z$ of the fuctions in $I$ is ivariant by flow of $X$ , namely
$$ \varphi^{X}_{t}\left( Z \right) \subseteq Z, \ \forall t.$$
Is this true? How is it proved?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: what is $X(M)$ leaves $I$ invariant means what ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that leaves $I$ invariant means that $X(f)(x)=df(x).X(x)\in I$, for every $f\in I$.

Let $\phi_t$ be the flow of $X$. for every $x\in Z$, ${d\over {dt}}_{t=0}f(\phi_t(x))=df(x).X(x)=X(f)(x)=0$ since $X(f)\in I$, implies that the function $t\rightarrow f(\phi_t(x))$ is contant, we deduce that for every $t$, $f(\phi_t(x))=f(\phi_0(x))=f(x)=0$ and  $\phi_t(x)\in Z$.

Comment: $X(f)$ is a function while $\mathrm{d}f$ is a form. In what sense can their values at a point $x$ be equal?